# Laravel datatables with complex joins not working

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am using yajra laravel datatables to get my datatable populated.

I have quite a complex query including various joins:

```
$activityList = DB::table('activities')
    ->select( 'u2.id as manager_id','u2.name as manager_name','u.id as user_id','u.name as user_name','p.id as project_id','p.project_name as project_name','p.customer_name as customer_name','activities.year as year')

->leftjoin('projects as p', 'p.id', '=', 'activities.project_id')
->leftjoin('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'activities.user_id')
->leftjoin('users_users as uu', 'u.id', '=', 'uu.user_id')
->leftjoin('users AS u2', 'u2.id', '=', 'uu.manager_id');

  $data = Datatables::of($activityList)->make(true);
  return $data;
```

I have my javascript:

```
activitiesTable = $('#activitiesTable').DataTable({
                scrollX: true,
                serverSide: true,
                processing: true,
                ajax: {
                        url: "{!! route('listOfActivitiesPerUserAjax') !!}",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ajaxData,
                        dataType: "JSON"
                    },
                columns: [
                    { name: 'u2.id', data: 'manager_id' , searchable: false , visible: false},
                    { name: 'u2.name', data: 'manager_name', width: '150px' },
                    { name: 'u.id', data: 'user_id' , searchable: false , visible: false},
                    { name: 'u.name', data: 'user_name' , width: '150px'},
                    { name: 'p.customer_name', data: 'customer_name' , width: '200px'},
                    { name: 'p.id', data: 'project_id' , searchable: false , visible: false},
                    { name: 'p.project_name', data: 'project_name', width: '200px'},
                    { name: 'activities.year', data: 'year' , searchable: false , visible: false},
                    {
                        name: 'actions',
                        data: null,
                        sortable: false,
                        searchable: false,
                        render: function (data) {
                            var actions = '';
                            return actions;
                        }
                    }
                    ],
                order: [[2, 'asc']],
```

I cannot make it work with serverside.

If I don't use serverside, everything is working fine but as soon as I set serverside, I get all data and limit number of records, searching, sorting is not working anymore.

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":[{"manager_id":13,"manager_name":"test manager","user_id":14,"user_name":"testuser","project_id":48,"project_name":"Test project","customer_name":"test customer","year":2017,"jan_com":10,"jan_otl":"0","feb_com":32,"feb_otl":"0","mar_com":0,"mar_otl":"0","apr_com":0,"apr_otl":"0","may_com":0,"may_otl":"0","jun_com":0,"jun_otl":"0","jul_com":0,"jul_otl":"0","aug_com":0,"aug_otl":"0","sep_com":0,"sep_otl":"0","oct_com":0,"oct_otl":"0","nov_com":0,"nov_otl":"0","dec_com":0,"dec_otl":"0"}],"queries":[{"query":"select count(*) as aggregate from (select `u2`.`id` as `manager_id`, `u2`.`name` as `manager_name`, `u`.`id` as `user_id`, `u`.`name` as `user_name`, `p`.`id` as `project_id`, `p`.`project_name` as `project_name`, `p`.`customer_name` as `customer_name`, `activities`.`year` as `year`, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=1,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=1,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=1,task_hour,0))) jan_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=1,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=1,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=1,activities.from_otl,0))) jan_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=2,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=2,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=2,task_hour,0))) feb_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=2,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=2,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=2,activities.from_otl,0))) feb_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=3,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=3,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=3,task_hour,0))) mar_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=3,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=3,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=3,activities.from_otl,0))) mar_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=4,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=4,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=4,task_hour,0))) apr_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=4,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=4,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=4,activities.from_otl,0))) apr_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=5,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=5,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=5,task_hour,0))) may_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=5,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=5,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=5,activities.from_otl,0))) may_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=6,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=6,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=6,task_hour,0))) jun_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=6,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=6,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=6,activities.from_otl,0))) jun_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=7,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=7,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=7,task_hour,0))) jul_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=7,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=7,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=7,activities.from_otl,0))) jul_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=8,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=8,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=8,task_hour,0))) aug_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=8,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=8,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=8,activities.from_otl,0))) aug_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=9,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=9,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=9,task_hour,0))) sep_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=9,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=9,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=9,activities.from_otl,0))) sep_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=10,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=10,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=10,task_hour,0))) oct_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=10,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=10,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=10,activities.from_otl,0))) oct_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=11,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=11,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=11,task_hour,0))) nov_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=11,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=11,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=11,activities.from_otl,0))) nov_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=12,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=12,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=12,task_hour,0))) dec_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=12,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=12,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=12,activities.from_otl,0))) dec_otl from `activities` left join `projects` as `p` on `p`.`id` = `activities`.`project_id` left join `users` as `u` on `u`.`id` = `activities`.`user_id` left join `users_users` as `uu` on `u`.`id` = `uu`.`user_id` left join `users` as `u2` on `u2`.`id` = `uu`.`manager_id` where (`year` = ?) and (`u2`.`id` = ?) group by `manager_id`, `manager_name`, `user_id`, `user_name`, `project_id`, `project_name`, `year`) count_row_table","bindings":["2017","13"],"time":1.2},{"query":"select `u2`.`id` as `manager_id`, `u2`.`name` as `manager_name`, `u`.`id` as `user_id`, `u`.`name` as `user_name`, `p`.`id` as `project_id`, `p`.`project_name` as `project_name`, `p`.`customer_name` as `customer_name`, `activities`.`year` as `year`, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=1,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=1,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=1,task_hour,0))) jan_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=1,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=1,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=1,activities.from_otl,0))) jan_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=2,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=2,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=2,task_hour,0))) feb_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=2,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=2,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=2,activities.from_otl,0))) feb_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=3,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=3,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=3,task_hour,0))) mar_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=3,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=3,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=3,activities.from_otl,0))) mar_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=4,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=4,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=4,task_hour,0))) apr_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=4,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=4,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=4,activities.from_otl,0))) apr_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=5,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=5,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=5,task_hour,0))) may_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=5,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=5,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=5,activities.from_otl,0))) may_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=6,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=6,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=6,task_hour,0))) jun_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=6,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=6,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=6,activities.from_otl,0))) jun_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=7,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=7,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=7,task_hour,0))) jul_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=7,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=7,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=7,activities.from_otl,0))) jul_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=8,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=8,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=8,task_hour,0))) aug_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=8,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=8,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=8,activities.from_otl,0))) aug_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=9,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=9,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=9,task_hour,0))) sep_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=9,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=9,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=9,activities.from_otl,0))) sep_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=10,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=10,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=10,task_hour,0))) oct_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=10,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=10,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=10,activities.from_otl,0))) oct_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=11,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=11,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=11,task_hour,0))) nov_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=11,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=11,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=11,activities.from_otl,0))) nov_otl, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=12,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=12,task_hour,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=12,task_hour,0))) dec_com, if(sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=12,task_hour,0))>0,sum(if(activities.from_otl=1 and month=12,activities.from_otl,0)),sum(if(activities.from_otl=0 and month=12,activities.from_otl,0))) dec_otl from `activities` left join `projects` as `p` on `p`.`id` = `activities`.`project_id` left join `users` as `u` on `u`.`id` = `activities`.`user_id` left join `users_users` as `uu` on `u`.`id` = `uu`.`user_id` left join `users` as `u2` on `u2`.`id` = `uu`.`manager_id` where (`year` = ?) and (`u2`.`id` = ?) group by `manager_id`, `manager_name`, `user_id`, `user_name`, `project_id`, `project_name`, `year`","bindings":["2017","13"],"time":0.92}],"input":{"year":["2017"],"manager":["13"]}}
```

You can see at the end, it doesn't add the limit or offset parameter.

Comment: Can you please post JSON response from your script?

Answer (score 0):

In the datatables demo application, the joins happen before the select statement. I can't say for sure if that is causing a problem as I have never used datatables with the fluent query builder, but it might be worth looking into. See the example code here:

https://datatables.yajrabox.com/fluent/joins

Basic Serivce Implementation:

https://datatables.yajrabox.com/services/basic

Comment: It doesn't change anything. If you don't use the fluent query builder, what do you use instead? And how is it working then?

Comment: I use Eloquent for the vast majority of my needs and other times just Collections. I also set the package up as a service so it handles all the querying automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Heads Up! When using join statements, you must follow the table. column approach on your js columns definition.

Example columns definition:

```
columns: [{data: 'id', name: 'posts.id'}, {data: 'name', name: 'users.name'}]
```